# Why isn't my BigDecimal calculator outputting the correct value?

Tags: ruby

I programmed a calculator:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

def addition()
  print "Enter the first number "
  number1 = BigDecimal(gets.chomp)
  print "Enter the second number  "
  number2 = BigDecimal(gets.chomp)
  sum = number1 + number2
  print sum
end
```

It is not giving the correct sum. If I enter `4.21` as number one and `2.11` for number two, I get `0.632E1`. If I enter `4.21` as number one and `2.11` for number two, I get `0.632E1`.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

That sum is *correct*. `0.632E1` is notation for 6.32.

To get a more "normal" looking number:

```
# BigDecimal built-in conversion to String
sum.to_s('F')
```

As shown in the [BigDecimal documentation for .to_s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-to_s)

You could also use:

```
# Converts to Float, you would lose precision for display, but at least you get
# the normal expected behaviour of a Float
sum.to_f  

# Converts to String with known precision (technically this just goes via Float)
sprintf( '%.4f', sum )
```